# How to slice Pandas datetime index to always pick the first day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

If I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
timestamp            lat        lon             sog                                     
2018-12-22 08:03:15  54.917200  13.358867      10.8                     
2018-12-22 08:04:05  54.916350  13.354700      10.8                     
2018-12-22 08:04:53  54.915533  13.350767      10.7  
2018-12-24 08:03:15  57.917200  9.358867       10.8                     
2018-12-24 08:04:05  57.916350  9.354700       10.8                     
2018-12-26 08:04:53  59.915533  5.350767       10.7
```

I would like to make a slice of the df to only work with the information from the first day. If I know the date I can simply

```
first_day = df.loc['2018-12-22']
```

But I would like to automatically do this for a lot of .csv files and they all have different starting dates. Is there a way to slice the Datetime index to get the first day only? something like:

```
first_day = df.iloc[:day1] ?
```

and end up with:

```
timestamp            lat        lon             sog                                     
2018-12-22 08:03:15  54.917200  13.358867      10.8                     
2018-12-22 08:04:05  54.916350  13.354700      10.8                     
2018-12-22 08:04:53  54.915533  13.350767      10.7
```

Comment: Maybe you could try to take the minimum and use its Y-M-D part for your slicing argument?

Comment: ^ then use `drop_duplicates` or you can can groupby by the month and return the min timestamp to use as a filter.

Comment: what is the `timestamp` dtype?

Comment: @Marat I would assume it's object!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first day (min date) and use boolean indexing:

```
for df in df_list:
    days = df.index.normalize()
    min_date = days.min()
    df[days == min_date]
```